# Kotlin Multi Platform, Access Swift Standard Library

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I have an `actual` class that I want to implement swift `Hashable` but I can't find the import for swift `Hashable` inside of Kotlin.

If I wanted to implement say `UIView` I could import it easily and use it as follows:

```kotlin
import platform.UIKit.UIView

actual final class Example actual constructor() : UIView(.... Stuff here)  {
    
}
```

But what about `Hashable`? and other things from the swift standard library? I can't find them inside `platfrom`, I have also looked inside `platfrom.objc`, but can't find the standard lib anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hashable` is defined in Swift, KMP doesn't support Swift interop at the moment. In Kotlin you can only use code that's available from ObjC.

But all `NSObject` subclasses are `Hashable` by default, so any object created from KMP will also be hashable.

Note that in the case of `NSObject`, the hash is based on the object pointer, not on object properties, as you may be used to in Swift. You can override this logic from Swift:

```swift
extension KObject {
    public override var hash: Int {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

or from Kotlin implementation:

```kotlin
override fun hash(): NSUInteger {
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: Yeah I found that you can force your object to be NSObject but all objects exported from KMP are NSObjects by default. The reason my object wasn't Hashable was because I was using a List of interfaces not the actual objects. I think that this means you can either type check in swift and then force cast or change the Interface to an abstract class (if it is appropriate), then swift knows the objects are NSObjects and therefor Hashable.

Comment: @PleaseHelpMe yeah, generics are weak point of KMP(because of ObjC), you have to force-cast in such cases.